# Python Selenium NoSuchElement when trying to webscrape

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I know this question has been asked before, but I have been through many of the Stack Overflow Solutions and nothing seems to be working for me. I am attempting to scrape a website for real estate data. I am able to click through the log in page and a second page, but when I arrive on the third page, I am stuck on clicking a link.

HTML Block:

```
<div id="m_wm_w6_m_pnlContent" class="css_content wgt_content">
     <table width="100%">
          <tbody><tr>
                <td><a id="m_wm_w6_m_lv_ctrl0_m_lnkWatch" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;m_wm$w6$m_lv$ctrl0$m_lnkWatch&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="white-space:nowrap; font-size:11px;">New Listing (186)</a> 
                 </td>
                 <td width="50%"><div style="background-color:#008770;width:100%;height:12px;border:solid 1px #C0C0C0;"></div></td>
                </tr>
```

I want to `click` on the link using selenium for the tag `"New Listing"` with `href="javascript:__doPostBack...`

My Code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get(url + login)

driver.find_element_by_id('clareity').send_keys(username)

driver.find_element_by_id('security').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('security').send_keys(password)

driver.find_element_by_id('loginbtn').click()

driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element_by_id('appColumn386').click()



#WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//html/body/form/div[3]/div[7]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a"))).click()
#WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=‘m_wm_w6_m_lv_ctrl0_m_lnkWatch’]"))).click()

#WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.staleness_of(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/form/div[3]/div[7]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a")))
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/form/div[3]/div[7]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a").click()
```

The commented code is some of the solutions I tried and didn't seem to get to work. I am getting `"NoSuchElement"` error even though when I check the Chrome dev tools, the element shows up. I have even tried both `XPaths` from `dev tools`, but it is still not able to find. I have also tried `time.sleep()` to let the page load. I might be missing something very easy here but have been stuck for a while, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: there are some odd characters in your xpath there: //*[@id=‘m_wm_w6_m_lv_ctrl0_m_lnkWatch’]"  (Not single quotes...)

Comment: this was the xpath i got when copying and pasting from Chrome dev tool

Comment: make sure to type in the single-quotes...  you could also try going by link text.  Something like: //a[text()='New Listing (186)']

Answer (score 0):

Since the `text` is in `between a tag`, I would recommend you to use `LINK_TEXT` as a first option.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "New Listing (186)"))).click()
```

**or**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "New Listing"))).click()
```

PS : Make sure that you are not in `any new tab or windows.` since you've mentioned that you are in `3rd page.`